# Сохранение класса присвоенного через JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть на сайте WP фильтр товаров, сделал при помощи js(jquery) сворачивание вкладок фильтра - добавляю класс при клике на заголовок и вкладки фильтра открывается-закрывается. Но при фильтрации идет ajax запрос, фильтр обновляется и мои классы исчезают. Как их можно сохранить. Пробовал через localStorage, при перезагрузке страницы обновляется, при ajax фильтрации нет.
Сайт на WP, плагин фильтра Search & Filter PRO, код добавления класса:

```
$('.sf-field-taxonomy-brand h4').click(function(){
    $('.sf-field-taxonomy-brand ul').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hadClass = $('.sf-field-taxonomy-brand ul').hasClass('open');
...

// after фильтр обновляется
if (hadClass)
  $('.sf-field-taxonomy-brand ul').addClass('open');
```